# How do I remove the dark side bars from this slideshow?

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am working with this template - http://startbootstrap.com/templates/modern-business/

I would just LOVE to know, how do I removed the 'On hover' effect of the slideshow to make it so the grey at either side isn't there at all!

Thanks for any help!

Comment: And we would just LOVE if you could show us some code to have an idea what's this about.

Comment: How am I supposed to show you all the html and css? :-/ I gave you a link to the slideshow, can you not inspect that? :S

Comment: Read this before asking questions here, please: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: This is also important: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find

```
.carousel-control.left {
background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 0px, transparent 100%);
background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
```

and

```
.carousel-control.right {
background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 0px, transparent 100%);
background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
```

in the CSS of the template and delete them.

Answer (score 0):

Remove this code from the css:

```
.carousel-control:hover,.carousel-control:focus{
    color:#fff;
    text-decoration:none;
    filter:alpha(opacity=90);
    outline:0;
    opacity:.9
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to remove the dark-grey hover-effect then remove the following opacity-rules from `bootstrap.min.css`.

Before:

```
.carousel-control:hover, .carousel-control:focus {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    filter: alpha(opacity=90);
    outline: 0;
    opacity: .9;
}
```

After:

```
.carousel-control:hover, .carousel-control:focus {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    outline: 0;
}
```